# Access 2003 FORMS: when I set at runtime with VBA the "RowSource" for a ListBox persist even if I close and then open

Tags: ms-access, vba

Access 2003 FORMS: when I set at runtime with VBA the "RowSource" for a ListBox persist even if I close and then open...

How to fix this, I would like to have clean "RowSource" when I open a new form...

Comment: Are you saving the form's design at some point? Hitting Ctrl-S on the keyboard after the Rowsource has been set?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can set the RowSource during form load.

```
Private Sub Form_Load()
    Dim strSql As String
    strSql = "SELECT f.id, f.fname FROM foo AS f ORDER BY f.fname;"
    Me.lstNames.RowSource = strSql
End Sub
```

Comment: so in this case I would assign to an empty string... But this behaviour doesn't seems to me too good. I set the rowsource at runtime, and then the last used will open when i reopen the form...

Comment: I don't understand.  With my suggestion, the form will always open with the lstNames.RowSource as it's set at Form_Load.

Comment: it's true, but my list should not load the data when the form loads, because at this moment it doenst know what to query. What im doing is  a search box, and when you press search a listbox will be filled with data. But in my problem, the list is filled at startup with the last search made... so at startup i set the rowsource to "" nothing

Comment: Either don't save the form after your code alters the RowSource, or set the RowSource at form load as I suggested.  Or you could disable  the listbox (set Enabled = No, or Visible = No)... and not worry about what's in the listbox ... once the user gives you selection criteria, set the RowSource and enable it.

Answer (score 1):

Setting the RowSource of the List Box changes the Form's design. Access wants to save those changes for you (actually, I think the default behavior is to ask). If you want to close the form without changes, put this code in a Command Button's OnClick:

```
DoCmd.Close acForm, Me.Name, acSaveNo
```

The last parameter tells Access to not save the changes. Another alternative is what HansUp gave you in his second comment to his answer--just disable the List Box. Then when you figure out what its RowSource should be (on user input), set the RowSource & the Enabled property.